# Extension of diffeomorphisms preserving bilateral bounds of the derivatives

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, real-analysis, differential-topology

Suppose $f$ is a $C^k (1\leq k\leq\infty)$ function from the unit ball $\mathcal{B}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself, which is a diffeomorphism from the domain to its image, with the upper and lower bounds of the norm of derivative of $f$: $$ \|df(x)\| \leq \alpha < 1, \|df^{-1}(x)\| \leq \beta, ~\forall x\in \mathcal{B} $$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real constants.

Could $f$ be extended to a $C^k$ function $F$ from the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself, still satisfying 
$$ \|dF(x)\| \leq \alpha, \|dF^{-1}(x)\| \leq \beta, ~\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n $$ and additionally 
$$ F(x) \rightarrow \infty \mathrm{~when~} x \rightarrow \infty ? $$

Hence we can use the *Hadamard's global inverse function theorem* to show that $F$ is a diffeomorphism.

There are related results such as *Kirszbraun’s theorem* and *Whitney's extension theorem*, but they are not enough.

If it is true, this result will lead to the global stable and unstable manifold theorem in the thoeory of dynamical systems.

Comment: Are you sure? Here $df(x)$ may be singular already at some point of $B$. I think you had in mind an hypothesis on $\|df(x)^{-1}\|$ instead, like in Hadamard's theorem in fact.

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected the description of the problem.

Comment: Of course you also need to assume that $f(B)=B$, as assuming just $f(B)\subset B$ allows non-injective locally invertible maps $f:B\to B$

Comment: Thanks very much. The origin condition is that $f$ is a diffeomorphism to its image. I have improperly dropped this condition.